# Unable to get data from query results from Twitter API

Tags: android, android-listview

I am new to Android.  I can't get my ListView to populate.  I am aware that this question has been asked on SO multiple times before and I have tried the things suggested in other questions (e.g. making sure my orientation is set to vertical, calling notifyDataSetChanged etc) and it still won't work.  My activity class is as follows:

```
package com.michaelnares.twitterclient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by michael on 01/05/2014.
 */
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

    EditText queryEditText = null;
    String queryText = null;
    private Context context = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);
        queryEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.queryEditText);
        queryText = (queryEditText.getText().toString());
        final Context context = this;

        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (queryText.equals(null)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "You did not enter a query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    new SearchAsyncTask().execute();
                    }
            }
        });
    } // ends onCreate()

    private class SearchAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>>
    {

       private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);
        private ArrayList<String> searchResults;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Getting data...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            APIClient client = new APIClient();
            searchResults = client.getQueryResults(queryText);
            return searchResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> results)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            results.addAll(searchResults);
            final ListView searchListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchListView);
            final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            searchListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
} //ends class
```

and my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp" >

  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/search"
          android:textSize="25dp"/>

 <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/queryEditText"
          android:ems="20"/>

 <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/query"
        android:id="@+id/queryButton"
        android:textSize="15dp"/>

 <ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchListView">
        </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my API client class also:

```
package com.michaelnares.twitterclient;

import android.util.Log;
import twitter4j.*;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by michael on 01/05/2014.
 */
public class APIClient

{

    ArrayList<String> statusArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> searchArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getHomeTimeline() {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(AuthConstants.API_KEY)
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(AuthConstants.API_SECRET)
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(AuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(AuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
        try {
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();


                List<Status> statuses = twitter.getHomeTimeline();

            statusArrayList.clear();
            for (Status status : statuses)
            {
                statusArrayList.add(status.toString());
            }

        }

        catch (TwitterException e)
        {
            Log.e(LogConstants.LOG, "Failed to get home timeline tweets: " + e.getErrorMessage());
        }

        return statusArrayList;
        } // ends getHomeTimeline() method

    public ArrayList<String> getQueryResults(String userQuery)
    {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                    .setOAuthConsumerKey(AuthConstants.API_KEY)
                    .setOAuthConsumerSecret(AuthConstants.API_SECRET)
                    .setOAuthAccessToken(AuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN)
                    .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(AuthConstants.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
            Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
            searchArrayList.clear();
            try {
                Query query = new Query(userQuery);
                QueryResult result;
                result = twitter.search(query);
                List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
                int count = 0;
                searchArrayList.clear();
                for (Iterator<Status> i = tweets.iterator(); i.hasNext();)
                {
                    Status tweet = i.next();
                    count++;
                    if (count == 10)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    searchArrayList.add("@" + tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + tweet.getText());
                } // ends for loop
            } // ends try block
            catch (TwitterException e)
            {
                Log.e(LogConstants.LOG, "Failed to search tweets: " + e.getErrorMessage());
            }
        return searchArrayList;
        } // ends getQueryResults() method
} // ends class
```

I'm really struggling to work out what the issue is.

Comment: I'm getting "failed to search tweets - null".  I will add my API client class as well.

Comment: Instead of e.getErrorMessage(), log the `TwitterException`'s call stack. This will give you more information. Also, please consider revising your question (or at least changing the title) -- the ListView would seem to be unrelated to the actual problem.

Comment: I have changed the title.  What I am going to try doing is altering my API client and doing System.out.println()s in Java, as like you say I don't think this has anything to do with the ListView.  Hopefully that should help.